# how to copy vhd to RM based subscription using powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am looking for Powershell script to copy vhd to subscription using Resource Manager deployment model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vhd's are stored in Azure storage page blobs, and the storage API works independently of how an account is created (classic vs ARM). It's even independent of subscription. You just need your storage account's name and key.

So you should just be able to copy via something like:

```
$DestContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<name>"
   -StorageAccountKey "<key>"

Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer "<containername>" -DestContext $DestContext
```

And `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` should work the same, regardless how the storage account was created.

Comment: Maybe they've changed the cmdlet recently, but shouldn't there be a srcblob/srccontainer in there somewhere ;)

Comment: @MichaelB That's left as an exercise to the reader. :)  My answer was specifically directly at the misunderstanding around accessing storage accounts created via ARM, and that storage accounts are accessed in a different way.